# Unable to use Sudo and Could not resolve 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, sudo

I could not use sudo function in my rasbian and when i try to update or upgrade using my terminal i am incurring following error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo 
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-get update
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease

Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.raspberrypi.org'
```

Following is the result of permissions for Sudo

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 139584 Jan 11 2016 /usr/bin/sudo
```

kindly let me know what is the issue with my Raspberry

Comment: Two different questions - perhaps break them up? What is the result of `ls -l /usr/bin/sudo`?

Comment: @SiKing: this is the output --->  pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 139584 Jan 11  2016 /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: Please update the original question with the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

From the output of your `ls`, it appears that you (or someone) messed with the system files on your Pi and broke things.

The permissions on sudo should be something like:

```
-r-s--x--x  1 root  wheel  168448 May  4  2016 /usr/bin/sudo
```

The "s" in the above is the "setuid bit" as per the error message, and the "root" is the "owned by uid 0" as per the error message.

Since you do not have sudo working, and you need sudo to fix this problem, the fix will be difficult. You could plug in the SD card into a Linux system and then fix the permissions, but I suspect there may be other things broken.

The simplest solution would be:

1. backup anything important
2. reinstall the OS
3. restore your backup
4. don't mess with the system files again, unless you know what your are doing

Comment: How should i reinstall the os, should i format my sd card again, also i would like to mention that i have edited conf file in /etc directory of rasbian, will this be a problem ?, how to install rasbian more accurately

Comment: You should update your question with contents from your edited conf file. I would just reinstall the image on your SD card and start over.

Comment: @DevanDevak Installing Raspbian is documented here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/ Anything else, you are doing custom work and you will need to describe what it is you are trying to achieve. That is probably a new question.

Comment: I am trying to install raspbian using laptop with ubuntu 16.04 LTS , i followed all the instructions, but i could not install the rasbian with the procedure cited in the link

Comment: I am getting a strange error, when i put sd card on micro card reader , and type df -h , my computer could not recognize new device, the new sd card is empty, i have formatted it

Comment: @DevanDevak We are definitely talking about a **new question** now!